# Toolbar and gulp/browsersync: body tag overwritten with comment

Tags: toolbar

In Drupal 10, with a gulp/browserSync sync to localhost:3000, I am getting the comments in web/core/modules/toolbar/toolbar.module showing up at the top of my page.

```php
// These are classes that toolbar typically adds to <body>, but this code
// executes before the first paint, when <body> is not yet present. The
// classes are added to <html> so styling immediately reflects the current
// toolbar state. The classes are removed after the toolbar completes
// initialization.
```

It looks like the first `<body>` tag in the comments is replacing the actual HTML body tag. If I edit this comment to *when body is not yet present*, the problem does not happen. (Yes, I know I should not edit core files; it was just a test to find the cause.)

The problem also does not happen when viewing the site without going through browsersync.

This may be more a browsersync problem, but it started happening with Drupal 10.

Comment: should also note, I had to remove the brackets for all <body> and <html> in the comments

Comment: This seems more of a bug report for maintainers than a question about Drupal that we could answer.

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3355381#comment-15106592

Comment: There is an issue with the patch https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3379245

Comment: Thank you for the issue notice. Rather than use the patch, I updated the .theme as per comment 7: https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3379245#comment-15181653 . As of yet, I have not seen the patch problems mentioned in the comments with logged in users who have toolbar permissions, logging out and getting the empty gap at the top.

Comment: Looks like this should now be fixed in 10.1.3: https://www.drupal.org/node/3383056

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there is a comment reporting this is a bug and that it was fixed in  drupal.org/node/3383056.